# How to stop Matlab rounding up doubles?

Tags: matlab, rounding

```
e = realmin;
x = 1 - e;

fprintf('x is %g',x);
```

Produces `x is 1`. However, I am trying to set `x` to 1 minus a small epsilon, which is equal to `realmin`.

How do I stop the rounding up?

Comment: Isn't epsilon intended to be 0?

Comment: how about using [eps](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)? It is a bit bigger though.

Comment: @DedekMraz - It still says (1 - eps) is 1.

Comment: @poitroae - Its intended to be a very small non-zero number. Instead of allowing the choice of epsilon to influence the result, I want to set it as the smallest number less than 1 in Matlab.

Comment: @Legendre: could you tell me what you get for `eps(1)` - I don't have Matlab

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but `(1-eps)` does not give `1`, it shows `1.00000`; this is MATLAB's way of showing that it has been rounded in the display.  Whereas, `1-realmin` really does give `1`.  In fact, even `(1-10^200 * realmin)` gives `1`, so it happens with much larger numbers than `realmin`!

Comment: Thanks @jazzbassrob - I thought that should work and was confused with @Legendre's comment. I also needed time to learn that `1.00000` is display rounding and `1` is actually `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the difference between the exponents of `realmin` and of `1` -- the difference is about `308`.  This means that Matlab would need about 308 digits (all of them 9 apart from the last one perhaps) to represent `1-realmin` but Matlab, of course, works natively with double precision floating point numbers which provide only 15 or 16 decimal digits.

The 'problem' is one of failing to understand one of the subtleties of floating-point arithemtic.  The nearest representable double precision number to `1 - realmin` is `1`.

The function you want is Matlab's `eps`.  While `1 - eps(1)` is represented (with `format long` set) as `1.000000000000000` evaluation of `1 - eps(1) == 1` returns `0` or `false` if you prefer.  Here it *is* the representation that is a bit confusing.

Comment: Additional info: 1 - 0.000001 gives 0.999999, while 1 - 0.0000001 gives 1.

Comment: `1 - 0.0000001` does not produce the answer `1` when you have `format long` on, it produces the correct answer `0.999999900000000`.